# Understanding function definitions inside object with different syntaxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and want to take your help in understanding 2 given code snippets which according to me is doing same stuff but have different syntaxes. I am sure they would have some difference, its just that I am not able to figure out when to use which syntax.

Also in snippet 2 what does GET and VALUE means?

Snippet 1

```
function Base(){
    this.title="BASE";
}

Base.prototype.sayHi=function(name){
    console.log("Hi "+ name);
}
var child=Object.create(Base.prototype);
child={

    sayHello:function()
    {
        console.log("Hello");
    }

}
```

Snippet 2

```
var child=Object.create(Base.prototype,{

    sayHello:{
        value:function(){
            console.log(" Hello");
        }
    },

    getThree:{
        get:function(){
            return 1+2;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get and Value are inherited  from default Object model. On the snippet 1 it is defined a constructor that initializes attribute tittle. The seconde one just initializes it with two methods. They show the dynamic side of Javascript object prototyping, where you can do the same thing using different techniques.